# Why cant this flatMap work?

Tags: scala

I want a nested list of (k,v) tuples transformed to a flat list of (v,k) in Scala 2.9.3. I tried putting the required function literal in a flatMap. But this happens:

```
scala> List( List( (1,"123"), (1,"abc")), List( (45, "qwer")) ).flatMap{ case (k,v) => (v,k) }
<console>:16: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: List[(Int, java.lang.String)]
       List( List( (1,"123"), (1,"abc")), List( (45, "qwer")) ).flatMap{ case (k,v) => (v,k) }
                                                                              ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value v
       List( List( (1,"123"), (1,"abc")), List( (45, "qwer")) ).flatMap{ case (k,v) => (v,k) }
                                                                                        ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value k
       List( List( (1,"123"), (1,"abc")), List( (45, "qwer")) ).flatMap{ case (k,v) => (v,k) }
                                                                                      ^
```

Why is this happening to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `flatten` and `map` here, not `flatMap`.

`flatMap` on `List[a]` takes function `A => List[B]` (actually not `List[B]`, but any collection of `B`) and returns `List[B]`. This is not your case.

You have a function `C => B`, not `List[C] => List[B]`. In your case `A` is `List[C]`.

`map` on `List[A]` takes a function `A => B` and returns `List[B]`.

```
val listOfLists = List( List( (1,"123"), (1,"abc")), List( (45, "qwer")) )
listOfLists.flatten.map{ case (k,v) => (v,k) }
// List[(String, Int)] = List((123,1), (abc,1), (qwer,45))
```

You could use `flatMap`, but for `List[List[A]]` you have to provide a function that takes `List[A]` as an argument like this:

```
listOfLists.flatMap( _.map{case (k,v) => (v,k)} )
// List[(String, Int)] = List((123,1), (abc,1), (qwer,45))
```

Comment: @aitchnyu: I didn't noticed you have a `List[List[A]]`. Fixed. Try again.

Comment: This explains everything! My requirement was not even in the question, since I was using Spark distributed collection which have similar API like scala collections(I was reproducing my issue with List).

Comment: The `.swap` method might come in handy here :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
scala> val m =  List( List( (1,"123"), (1,"abc")), List( (45, "qwer")) )
m: List[List[(Int, java.lang.String)]] = List(List((1,123), (1,abc)), List((45,qwer)))

scala> m.flatten.map { case (k,v) => (v,k) }
res0: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((123,1), (abc,1), (qwer,45))
```

Basically you first flatten the nested list, then map to reorder the tuples.